# call a https REST service from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, https

I try to get data form this rest service. I a browser it works fine. Now I try to do this in VBA to display the data in Excel

https://energidataservice.dk/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=ec797392-7ba5-4c3a-b021-8ae302ac295a&limit=5

I believe it has to do with https and TSL. When I code this in C# and add this line it works. I just don't know how to do this in VBA

```
'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 - object required

Dim reader As New WinHttpRequest
Dim json As New JSONParser
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim url As String
url = ws.[EDS_URL]

' reader.Option(9) = 2720 - invalid procedure call
reader.Open "GET", url, False

reader.Send ' automation error
```

Without the TSL part I get automation error in the last line

Answer (score 5):

Try this, accept as solution if it helps

```
Sub GetData()
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
url = "https://www.energidataservice.dk/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=ec797392-7ba5-4c3a-b021-8ae302ac295a&limit=5"
objHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/json"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405"
objHTTP.send ("")


Debug.Print objHTTP.Status
If objHTTP.Status = "200" Then
    MsgBox (objHTTP.responseText)
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi
It seemed to have solved the problem on my Windows 10 machine, but not on my Windows 7. I don't know if this is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your C# code. Compile it as a Class Library, then expose to COM.
Now you can load the .dll created to the VBA references.
Use it as you would do with any COM server.